# php 7 data truncate from mysql

Tags: mysql, php-7, truncate

i get the data from database like this:

```
$Le_SQL = "SELECT * FROM crm_temps WHERE Id='$leId'";   


if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $Le_SQL )) {


    /* Récupère un tableau associatif */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
```

when i print it `printf ("%s",  $row[3]);`
it show all the string : `Installation Ubuntu sur Server UNIX`

but when i put the `$row[3]` in input type text, it is truncated `Installation`

i have tried like this:

```
<b>Description:</b> <input type=text name=Description size=50 max=200 value=<?php echo $row[3]; ?>><br>
```

or like this:

```
echo "<b>Description:</b> <input type=text name=Description size=50 max=200 value= $row[3]><br>";
```

both result the same, instead i got Installation Ubuntu sur Server UNIX, i get just Installation.

so why the data is truncated ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP. You are generating totally invalid HTML.

Comment: Use quotes for the html attributes.

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to sql injection attacks